# Images from amazon s3 are not visible in meteor template

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

Does anyone tell me why images from s3 are not visible in my meteor template?
If I type image url in browser it is showing that image, but not in my template.
So this is my template code:

```
<template name="test">
  <div>
    <img src="http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/1_p.jpg " />
  </div>        
  ...  
</template>
```

And error coming is:

Refused to load the image 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/1_p.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data: 'self' http://*.googleapis.com https://*.googleapis.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://*.bootstrapcdn.com https://*.bootstrapcdn.com".

test:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y

Comment: Have you tried loading other images from the web and do they work?  If other images do not work then it is something to do with your code.  If other images do work then it is something to do with your s3 settings.

Comment: I just tried in chrome and it is giving CSP error.

Comment: Can you show us the error message and your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I resolved this problem. Actually I'm using browser-policy package and in order to access data on s3 I need to add s3 url in whitelist..